# Set leading of paint / fontmetrics in android

Tags: android, text, canvas

I'm using a custom font and adding text to a canvas with a Paint object in android, e.g:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

paint.setTextSize(29);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setTypeface(font);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)); // Text Overlapping Pattern

final TextPaint tp = new TextPaint(paint);
final TextPaint tpStroke = new TextPaint(strokePaint);

// canvas.translate(15, 5);
canvas.translate(20, 5);

StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(textOne.getText().toString(), tp, (finalBitmapOne.getWidth()-10), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

sl.draw(canvas);
```

I'm not happy with the leading / line height, how can I adjust it?

I can *get* the leading via:

```
FontMetrics fmPaint = paint.getFontMetrics();
fmPaint.leading;
```

But how can I adjust it?

Comment: Tried `fmPaint.leading = x;`?

Comment: Yes,    FontMetrics fmPaint = paint.getFontMetrics();
        fmPaint.leading = 2; - doesn't seem to effect anything?

Comment: Try a huge number, like 30. It's extra space to add (in pixels, I suspect).

Comment: I have tried large numbers. And I've tried getFontMetricsInt(); too. I've also tried negative numbers, as I'm trying to reduce the line height. The text is rendered all capitals, and the default line height is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`getFontMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getFontMetrics%28android.graphics.Paint.FontMetrics%29) (emphasis mine):

> Return the font's **recommended** interline spacing, given the Paint's settings for typeface, textSize, etc. If metrics is not null, return the fontmetric values in it.

You don't set this to change spacing, you read this to determine what the recommended spacing should be. You'll have to reposition coordinates manually yourself, i.e. translating the canvas again between drawing each line.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds easier to edit the font itself than to write all the code to draw each line.